# Google Cloud - Zonal vs multi-regional interruption

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I notice when provisioning some products (Compute Engine, Cloud SQL) we need to specify a **Zone**... Does that mean Compute Engine / Cloud SQL are running in a specific Zone? What happens **if the whole Zone goes down** ? will it lead to interruptions?

vs Cloud Buckets that can span **multi-region** but within Europe, US or Asia. Does that mean if the **whole geography goes down** - for ex. Europe - it will lead to interruptions despite multi-region

Can anyone clarify  pls. what it means to set Location (Regional or Zonal) when provisioning any product in Google Cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Zonal resources like Compute Engine or Cloud SQL (not running in HA mode) can be interrupted by an problem in a single zone. You would avoid this problem with Compute Engine by creating a regional instance group behind a load balancer.

You are also correct that a multi-region bucket could go down if all the regions the bucket data is stored in become unavailable. Google gives an SLA on multiregional Cloud Storage of 99.99%, but that isn't 100%.

Setting the region or zone for a resource determines where the resource is provisioned and sometimes where it is available. Exactly how this works depends on the specific thing being provisioned.